# Add image on function alert javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code:

```
var easter_egg = new Konami();
easter_egg.code = function() { alert('Konami code!'); }
easter_egg.load();
```

I would like to show an image on "Konami code!"

Comment: Alert boxes are text-only. You could use a popup, but there's more effort involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are going to have to design a custom popup.  A quick search gave me http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ that might get you where you want to go.  The built in "alert()" doesn't support anything except text.